# Нужны ли кавычки в названиях набережных?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, прописная-строчная, кавычки, названия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли брать в кавычки названия набережных, какое правило здесь работает? Например: набережная "Цветочный вал", набережная "Чёрный тюльпан".

Comment: Набережная "чёрный тюльпан"... Вообще не звучит. Интересно, в каком городе есть такая набережная?

Comment: @Зонтик, в Хабаровске иногда так называют, поскольку памятник погибшим афганцам недалеко от набережной (хотя это неофициальное название набережной). В любом случае это лишь пример, хочется понять, какое правило написания здесь работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, что здесь надо использовать следующие рекомендации ["Грамоты"](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5#:%7E:text=%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5,%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0.):

> ...в названиях улиц, площадей, бульваров и т. п. с прописной буквы пишутся все слова, кроме родовых терминов (самих слов *улица, площадь, переулок, проспект, бульвар* и т. п.), а также слов *года, лет.* Таким образом, правильно: *улица Каретный Ряд, улица Кузнецкий Мост, улица Борисовские Пруды, площадь Никитские Ворота.*

К этому "и т. п." относятся и названия набережных — чем же они хуже названий улиц (Сущёвский Вал, Земляной Вал, Бутырский Вал, Нижний Вал, Новый Вал)?

Пишем с прописной, но без кавычек:
*набережная Цветочный Вал, набережная Чёрный Тюльпан.*

Comment: Так просто, лаконично, понятно — класс!!! А по ссылке прям увело в тему большой буквы второго слова, исторически связанного с его прямым значением... Здóрово!

Comment: Спасибо, Саша! Я *специально* оставила все мнения и все примеры "Грамоты", связанные с этой темой. Самой было интересно.