# Нужны ли кавычки в названиях небоскрёбов?

Tags: ономастика, кавычки, названия

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли кавычки в названиях небоскрёбов, какое правило здесь работает? "Грамота.ру" отвечает противоречиво... В одном случае пишет без кавычек: *Эмпайр-стейт-билдинг* (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20252994)), а в другом — с кавычками: *"Бурдж-Халифа"* (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=300927)). Так как же правильно?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (19.04.2023)**

Про названия башен "Грамота.ру" пишет следующее (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=244201)).

**Вопрос № 244201**

> Здравствуйте, уважаемые грамотники! :)
> Как правильно: В Сиэтле есть Башня Космическая игла. Прописные, кавычки?
> Очень жду.
> Ваша Буква.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Обычно название этой башни просто транслитерируют: *башня Спейс Нидл*. При переводе предпочтительный вариант оформления: *башня "Космическая игла".*

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужны ли кавычки в названиях набережных?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473615/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: @Зонтик, это всё-таки разные вопросы, касаются разных объектов...

Comment: Но правило одно =)

Answer (score 2):

Здесь, по всей видимости, вы неправильно поняли. Пример с Эмпайр-стейт-билдинг там написан корректно, без кавычек. Это, вероятно, обусловлено тем, что мы говорим не о абстрактной категории, вроде названия фирмы, а о названии конкретного здания. Образно говоря, это его имя, как имя реки или горы. Такие случаи не заключают в кавычки.
Пример с Бурдж-Халифа связан совершенно с другим случаем. Там иной контекст. Говорится о здании в Чечне, которое называют чеченской "Бурдж-Халифа". "Бурдж-Халифа" берётся в кавычки, чтобы обозначить, что это переносное значение и что это не тот самый арабский небоскрёб.
Почему же тогда не взяли в кавычки всё сочетание "чеченский Бурдж-Халифа"? Да просто потому, что небоскрёб действительно чеченский. Прилагательное не подразумевает переносного значения.
Другой вопрос, почему «Ахмат-тауэр», взятый в кавычки в тексте вопроса, "Грамота" не исправила. Предположу, что наличие и отсутствие кавычек в случае названий архитектурных объектов (включая небоскрёбы) зависит от культурного статуса объекта. Если сооружение на слуху, то и кавычек не нужно. Где та тонкая грань, когда нужно, а когда нет, не ответит никто.
Но конкретно по вашему вопросу можно ответить, что названия известных небоскрёбов пишутся без кавычек, кроме случаев, когда эти названия применяют в переносном значении.